# This Map in Ruby doesn't care about my if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I have this

```
def userposts
    posts = Post.where(user_id: params[:id])
    postnums = posts.map {|i| i.id }
    postsWithInfo = posts.map{|i| {
            post: i,
            recipe: i.recipe,
            recipepic: rails_blob_path(i.recipe.pic) if i.recipe?,
            pics: i.pics.map{|p| rails_blob_path(p) }
    }}
    render json: {posts: postsWithInfo}, status: 200
end
```

recipe is null if there's no recipe, and that's what I want, but the problem is that recipepic is crashing the thing if i.recipe is null, and that if statement is doing nothing to stop it. Is there a way I can make it so that this works?

The error I get is

```
/home/dan/code/projects/project5/backend/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected `if' modifier, expecting '}'
...ails_blob_path(i.recipe.pic) if i.recipe?,
... ^~
/home/dan/code/projects/project5/backend/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '}'
...ath(i.recipe.pic) if i.recipe?,
... ^
/home/dan/code/projects/project5/backend/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting `end'
}}
^
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide more information. What is the definition of `Post.recipe`? What error do you get from the crash?

Comment: I recommend [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging yoru code.

Comment: There must be something wrong in your Ruby installation. User code should *never* be able to provoke a crash. In the absolute worst-case, it can `raise` an `Exception`. If your code crashes, it means your Ruby installation is broken.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear - you can't put an `if` statement inside a hash literal value like that. What is this code actually supposed to do? Not include the `recipepic` key if the model doesn't have a blob? Set it to nil?

Comment: @max you actually can put an `if` statement in a hash literal value, but you need parens: `{foo: ("bar" if true)}` gives `{:foo => "bar"}` and `{foo: ("bar" if false)}` gives `{:foo => nil}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

```
postsWithInfo = posts.map do |i| 
  {
    post: i,
    recipe: i.recipe,
    recipepic: i.recipe? ? rails_blob_path(i.recipe.pic) : nil,
    pics: i.pics.map{|p| rails_blob_path(p) }
   }
end
```

Comment: of course we don't know if the `Post` class has a method `recipe?`, added by @Dan Seminara, but ActiveRecord `has_one` does not add the interrogation method `recipe?`, only the association itself `recipe`, which can be used here in the ternary clause

Comment: This worked. Recipe has_one_attached pic, and posts can have a recipe, but not all do, so the recipe will be nil, but then you can't get a pic out of the recipe. I actually knew this syntax in JS, but I had no idea it worked in Ruby as well! Thanks for this answer!!